# error: narrowing conversion of ‘-58’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ [-Wnarrowing]

Tags: c++, unsigned-char

I'm trying to compile https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp on a Raspberry Pi, and I'm getting this error:

```
/home/pi/yaml-cpp/test/binary_test.cpp:11:38: error: narrowing conversion of ‘-58’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ [-Wnarrowing]
   11 |   std::string input{-58, -1, -99, 109};
      |                                      ^
```

I gather that I should explicitly declare the numbers inside the bracket as signed chars, as some older compilers might not do so by themselves. But I am wholly unfamiliar with this syntax: What does this line actually do?

Comment: `std::string` is a container of `char`s. `char` can be `signed` or `unsigned`, it's up to the implementation. You may be trying to compile code that was unportably written assuming `signed` chars on a platform that uses `unsigned` chars.

Comment: I expect that you could just comment out the test in lines 10 to 14 to get the library to continue building: [https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/master/test/binary_test.cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/master/test/binary_test.cpp)

Comment: @drescherjm I did just that, and it seems to work. But there's no way - in this context - do declare, that I want to use signed chars?